# Difference between c++20 coroutine and barebone Windows Fibers?

Tags: c++, windows, concurrency

I've built a Windows Application that uses the Windows Fiber API extensively, yet not on a very deep level (namely only CreateFiber, DeleteFiber and SwitchToFiber).

It is not supposed to run on Linux and thus does not need the abstraction c++ offers.

I read about the new minimal support of coroutines in c++20 and since I want the project to be as up-to-date as possible, I'm considering rebuilding the system using c++20 coroutines instead of the bare bone Windows Fibers. Now what I have not been able to figure out is if this change makes sense.
I understand that you cannot assess the situation since many factors play into it, but generally speaking does the c++ couroutine implementation build on the Windows Fiber and only builds a "wrapper" around it or does it add any other value, especially performance wise.

I read that it requires expensive new and delete calls to create coroutines, which is unfortunate and expensive.

Do you reckon the c++ Implementation of coroutines is faster in a basic usage system in comparison to using the Fiber API directly?
I understand that Fibers use a scheduler, but does that impact the performance significantly? I see how this is important for the usage, when I read the implementation of boost fibers vs. coroutine.

Comment: These are good questions, although it may be they are considered somewhat broad for SO, so it may get closed. Although I dare say there may be people with some good and useful answers to these questions. They will, though, be compiler dependent.

Comment: I suspect that this Windows API can be translated directly into coroutines; so it'll be faster to just do that and then run some benchmarks and get some real data to work with.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Do you have any suggestions how I could rephrase it/make it more specific, so it is clearer and more appropriate for SO? When I wrote the title I already assumed it will get downvoted, but I couldn't come up with a better title or specifications. c++20 coroutines lack compiler support from what I know, but that's a general problem most of these features have, so I didn't consider it worth mentioning

Comment: I'd guess coroutines uses the thread pool and not fibers.

Comment: Coroutines are definitely implemented in MS's own C++ compiler. Microsoft was the one who hijacked the standardization process in order to add a threading model to the C++ standard that's not horribly bad on Windows (std::threads are horribly bad on Windows), so it didn't surprise anyone that VC++ implemented coroutines right out of the gate.

Comment: C++ doesn't provide **any** concurrency support with coroutines. All it offers is a framework for clients to use. In other words, to introduce concurrency into couroutines you're going to have to write library code that implements awaiters and awaitables. [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt) provides those implementations based on Windows' thread pool, if you need some inspiration on what that might look like.

Comment: As for compiler support, MSVC [introduced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2015-rtm-vs) C++20 coroutine support with Visual Studio 2015. That's more than 6 years ago. You can expect substantially better support on MSVC than on any other compiler, especially with the Windows Runtime being asynchronous by default.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p1364r0.pdf